# Highlight text cells in one column if cell value is in a list in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, highlighting, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight certain cells that match to any other cell in a different column.  For example I have a huge list of names in column A, and in Column P I have a column of names that are not supposed to be contacted.  I want every name in column A that exists in column P to be highlighted.

I have tried conditional formatting however it won't accept multiple text entries.  I did have a simple duplicate format set up, however if I have multiple entries in A that are the same they are highlighted as well.  It is easy enough with numbers however as it is text I have found it much more difficult.

Can anyone help with a formula or such that could help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please select ColumnA, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,$P:$P,0))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK:

Comment: Don't need ISNUMBER:   =MATCH(A1,P:P,)